# Improve += operator performance

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing an application that must be very fast. I use Qt 5.5 with Qt Creator, the 64 bit MSVC2013 compiled version of Qt.

I used very sleepy CS to profile my application, and I saw that the function that took the most exclusive time was an operator+= overload (which is called, as you guess, a lot of times).

Here's the piece of code.

```
struct Coordinate
{
    float                   x;
    float                   y;

    Coordinate operator+=(const Coordinate &coord)
    {
        this->x += coord.x;
        this->y += coord.y;
        return (*this);
    }
};
```

I wondered if there were a way to improve performance of a function as simple as this one.

Comment: First, Qt has nothing to do with your code. It is the compiler that matters. Second, be sure to compile in Release configuration (with optimizations switched on). Then, so simple function is very likely to be inlined.

Comment: Also, you don't need to write `this->x`, it enough to write `x += coord.x`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`operator+=` is not quite defined the way you did. Rather, it [should be](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/operator_arith):

```
Coordinate& operator+=(const Coordinate &coord);
```

Note the return value of a reference.

This also has the benefit of not creating another copy.

Comment: I saw that, but since the reference is kind of a hidden pointer, which is if i am not wrong, the same size that the struct (composed of two float), i thought it would have no impact on the performance. It happens that the time elapsed in this function was ~23s, and now is ~14s. I validate this answer.

Comment: @Krapow such drastic change makes me think that you are measuring wrong thing. Make sure that you have optimisation enabled and any additional debug features turned off. I would expect any compiler to completely inline each operator instance, not generate actual function call and remove return value when it is not used.

Comment: @Krapow The difference is that if you don't return a reference, you force the copy constructor to be called and create a hard copy of the object. Anyway, you should not see such drastic changes in performance. Smells like incorrect benchmarking.

Comment: @Rvolver_Ocelot In fact it is in debug mode

Comment: @Krapow It doesn't make any sense to profile your code in debug mode. Debug and release mode are drastically different when it comes to performance.

Comment: Ok, I confirm this is REALLY different in release mode. I used to work a lot with GNU / G++ in console, I don't know very well the consequence of debug/ release mode (I guess it's not the same as setting the -g option so that valgrind gets the line of error). I rerun test with release mode, and it was like 10 times faster than in debug mode. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you are profiling Release configurion and compiler optimizations are enabled. Such calls should be [inlined](http://goo.gl/OMK9wG) by any decent compiler.